# Using piped commands to get a specific output in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm following a programming course and I'm trying to do a practice activity but I'm stuck. I have a file with the following list:

```
Monday       day
Tuesday      day
Easter       holiday
Monday       day
christmas    holiday
Tuesday      day
Friday       day
Thursday     day
thanksgiving holiday
```

What I'm trying to do is

1. sorting this list,
2. printing a new list containing only those names that are not repeated,
3. counting the number of times each word appears in the list, and
4. inserting a tab between the counter and the word.

This would be my desired output:

```
1    christmas    holiday
1    Easter       holiday
1    Friday       day
2    Monday       day
1    thanksgiving holiday
1    Thursday     day
2    Tuesday      day
```

I have tried using the following line of code:

```
cat my_file | sort | uniq -c | less
```

My problem is that words are not really sorted because words starting with capital letters would come before words starting with lowercase letters. Also, I don't know how to add the tab between the number and the word (in my output, there's only a space between them).

Could you help me?

Comment: You need to sort giving the key to do e.g. `sort -k1 file | uniq -c | column -t` should solve your problem. Here `-k1` arg to `sort` specifies sorting based on first column

Answer (score 2):

You may use `-f` to sort case-insensitive, and replacing spaces with tabs with `sed`(1). `cat` my be omitted from the pipe:

```
sort -f my_file | uniq -c | sed $'s/  */\t/g' | less
```

Note: The dollar sign in front of the `sed` parameter interprets `\t` as tab and not as `\t`.

If the first tab in each line is annoying, you can remove it with `sed` as well:

```
sort -f my_file | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//' | sed $'s/  */\t/g' | less
```

This produces:

```
1   christmas   holiday
1   Easter  holiday
1   Friday  day
2   Monday  day
1   thanksgiving    holiday
1   Thursday    day
2   Tuesday day
```

Finally, if you want to keep spaces between the second an the third column, you should omit the `g` (*replace all occurences of the search pattern*) from the second `sed` invocation:

```
sort -f my_file | uniq -c | sed 's/ *//' | sed $'s/  */\t/' | less
```

Result:

```
1   christmas    holiday
1   Easter       holiday
1   Friday       day
2   Monday       day
1   thanksgiving holiday
1   Thursday     day
2   Tuesday      day
```

Comment: Many sed insert a tab when you use `\t` in the substitution string; for example, GNU sed does.

Comment: I have now tested `\t` on Ubuntu where it works, but this doesn't work on macOS. It's probably a GNU extension.

Comment: Yes, POSIX doesn't prescribe what to do with backslash escapes in the replacement string (other than `\&` and `\1`/`\2` etc.)

Comment: This works, though there's one problem: I get the number and word together and the first tab comes before the number itself. How could I change that?

Comment: This is an example of what I got: `(tab)    1 christmas    holiday` , and this is what I want: `1    christmas    holiday`

Comment: The second and the third command line should avoid tabs at the beginning of each line. What OS are you using?

Comment: @clemens sorry for my late reply! I used the first command and I got a tab before the number instead of a tab between the number and the word. I'm using macOS High Sierra, if that helps

Comment: You should use the last command. The second and the last command remove leading spaces (tabs). See my post: *If the first tab in each line is annoying, you can remove it with sed as well:* Hope this helps.